# Two elliptic curves not dominated by a genus two curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $k$ be a number field and let $E$ and $E'$ be elliptic curve over $k$.

There is a genus two curve $X$ over $\overline{k}$ which dominates $E$ and $E'$.

**Question.** Is there a genus two curve $X$ over $k$ which dominates $E$ and $E'$?

Comment: The genus 2 curve over $\bar{k}$ descends to $L$ (including the morphisms), a finite extension of $L$. Replace $k$ by $L$. So, I don't see why not.

Comment: It seems unlikely that this would always be true. The question amount to finding an isogeny from $E \times E'$ to a principally polarised abelian surface which is not a product of elliptic curves (so will be the Jacobian of a genus 2 curve); if the image of the Galois representation on the Tate module of $E \times E'$ is very big, then such an isogeny probably does not exist.

Comment: @Mohan Yes, there is a finite field extension $L/k$ and a genus two (geometrically connected) curve $X$ over $L$ which dominates $E_L$ and $E_L'$. But this curve might not descend to $k$, and even if it does, the maps to $E_L$ and $E'_L$ might not descend to $k$.

Comment: @ulrich Yes, I thought it might be unlikely. Riemann-Hurwitz tells me that if the maps to $E$ and $E'$ have degree two, then there are precisely two branch points. If the map is of degree three, then there is precisely one branch point (and the ramification is total). I was thinking of just writing down two elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ with only one rational point, and playing around a bit. Would that work?

Comment: Yes, probably that or something similar might work. Actually it is not even clear that given any elliptic curve $E$ there exists a genus two curve dominating it (with the curve and map defined over $k$).